# Re-prompt Dialog input until guessing number is met -java

Tags: java, input, while-loop, dialog, prompt

I been trying to prompt the same input dialog, until the user guess the correct number, but I'm not sure how, any help would be appreciate! I'm pretty sure is how to implement the while loop but I don't know how exactly. The user input is a string parsed to int for the calculations

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nWelcome to Guess-       My-Number\nA GAME of CHANCE and SKILL\nLet's Play!\n\n");

            // input number
         String myGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 25:");
         int myGuess_int = Integer.parseInt(myGuess);

         final int NUMBER_TO_GUESS = 13;



           //good or bad guess??
         while(myGuess_int != NUMBER_TO_GUESS)
         {
            if(myGuess_int < NUMBER_TO_GUESS) //too low
            {
               String message = String.format("Your guess [ %s ] is too low...\nTry Again!\n", myGuess);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);   
            } 
            else //too high
            {
               String message = String.format("Your guess [ %s ] is too high...\nTry Again!\n", myGuess);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);             
            }

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 25:");
            myGuess_int = Integer.parseInt(myGuess);    

          }//end while


          String message = String.format("Your guess [ %s ] is the number...\nCongratulations!\n", myGuess);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);


      } //end main

   } //end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [do-while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)!

```
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nWelcome to Guess-       My-Number\nA GAME of CHANCE and SKILL\nLet's Play!\n\n");

         final int NUMBER_TO_GUESS = 13;

         //good or bad guess??
         String myGuess;
         int myGuess_int;
         do{
            // input number
            myGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 25:");
            myGuess_int = Integer.parseInt(myGuess);
            if(myGuess_int < NUMBER_TO_GUESS) //too low
            {
               String message = String.format("Your guess [ %s ] is too low...\nTry Again!\n", myGuess);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);   
            } 
            else //too high
            {
               String message = String.format("Your guess [ %s ] is too high...\nTry Again!\n", myGuess);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);             
            }

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number between 1 and 25:");
            myGuess_int = Integer.parseInt(myGuess);    

          }while(myGuess_int != NUMBER_TO_GUESS);//end while


          String message = String.format("Your guess [ %s ] is the number...\nCongratulations!\n", myGuess);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);


      } //end main

   } //end class
```

Comment: Yeah I tried with a do-while loop but I get this error instead:

`error: cannot find symbol
        while(myGuess_int != NUMBER_TO_GUESS);
              ^
  symbol:   variable myGuess_int
  location: class Guess`

Comment: Edited now, should be able to access it since it is declared in the outer scope

Comment: I've running without luck, when I declared the variables outside of the do-while loop, the compiler show an error :

`error: cannot find symbol
myGuess_int = Integer.parseInt(myGuess);`

So I don't think it will let me declare outside the do-while loop...Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use do while loop in your criteria,

the scenario will be like:

```
do { 
     // accept prompt from user

     // display error message using if else statement

} while (myGuess_int != NUMBER_TO_GUESS);  // loop again if input not match
```